# How to disable fringe in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

First, I try to use `(fringe-mode -1)`, as picture below, there is a very thin fringe on the right of linum line.

[image]

And then, I try to use `(set-fringe-mode '(0 . 0))` to specify the left-fringe and right-fringe to zero. The fringes disappear. But I got a very strange appearance. While the Emacs start up, the frame will be thinner and thinner, until narrow to a very thin line(I don't how to explain it, see the pictures below).

1. startup - loading dotfiles
   [image]
2. getting thiner
   [image]
3. finally
   [image]

And now, I set `(set-fringe-mode '(0 . 1))`, and there will be one fringe on the right of buffer.

Comment: Could you link to a screenshot of your whole window? I can't quite see what the issue is from your current screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had updated screenshots.

Comment: Thinner than last time you started Emacs in the same X session, or how? Do you restart Emacs often (why)?

Comment: You seem to have a large number of extensions. Is this reproducible with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Updated more screenshots

Answer (score 16):

How about `(set-fringe-mode 0)`? That's the value for `no-fringes` in `fringe-styles` alist.

If that doesn't work, too, I think you should submit a bug report.

Comment: Same as `(set-fringe-mode '(0 . 0))`

Comment: Works for me in Windows and in virtualized Ubuntu with Emacs 24. What's your version of Emacs? Have you tried to reproduce this starting with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. When I `(scroll-bar-mode -1)`, then `(set-fringe-mode '(0 . 0))`, try to resizing the frame. This will happen.

Comment: It's a bug all right. It doesn't show up in Windows, but I can confirm it in virtualized Ubuntu.

Comment: So feel free to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get the recipe after starting with 'emacs -Q', I am newbie to the Emacs lisp, I don't how to track the startup trace.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "startup trace". You second comment here contains all the instructions necessary to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I mean what's the meaning of 'emacs -Q', and what can I do after that to debug?

Comment: `emacs -Q` means that you normally have to try to reproduce the bug in Emacs started without additional packages or customizations. That's what running `emacs -Q` in console does. You don't need to do that now because I've already checked that. The "debugging" bit is also not relevant since the bug doesn't cause Emacs to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I had a similar issues and adding `setq` fixed my issue.
 Making the line:

```
 (setq set-fringe-mode 0)
```